# Require Jupyter Password across all Conda Environments

Tags: anaconda, jupyter

I am looking to allow users on a cluster to set up their own conda environments.

However, across all users, I want to force them to use a password to log in to Jupyter, regardless of whether or not they are launching from their own conda environment or from the root environment. I know I can globally set conda parameters by modifying the `.condarc` file in the root Anaconda directory. Is there an equivalent file for globally requiring jupyter password use/setting jupyter configs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do **not** want users to launch their own notebook, if you have a case with multiple users using notebooks you should use [JupyterHub](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). [JupyterHub](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is your solution; [JupyterHub](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has been developed for that, and not using JupyterHub will lead to the same pains a [Parsing HTML with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

[JupyterHub](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) works with Containers, if you use container, but works also if you only have conda envs, or just system Python. If you have centralized auth (OAuth/LDAP) JupyterHub hook into that, if you prefer PAM, PAM work. If you have SLURM/MPI, JupyterHub hook into that. If you need to use SSH, JupyterHub can undersand it. There is a [full org on GitHub](https://github.com/jupyterhub/) conveniently also named [JupyterHub](https://github.com/jupyterhub/) of plugins for JupyterHub to bend it to your will and needs... and if you have a specific case note covered, open a bug report or write a plugin that cover yours, and maybe later it can be added to the org !

So I believe JupyterHub is what you are looking for.

And also, you shouldn't install the notebook in each environment. The notebook server should only be installed once system wide (or once per users sometime). You should **only install ipykernel** in each env.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback - sounds exactly like what we're looking for.